# $a, b$ are two constants with $|a| > 0$. If the equation $||x − a| − b| = 3$ has three distinct solutions for $x$, find the value of $b$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

$a, b$ are two constants with $|a| > 0$. If the equation $||x − a| − b| = 3$ has
three distinct solutions for $x$, find the value of $b$?

I came up with these four equations

$x = a+b+3, a+b-3, a-b-3, a-b+3$

Equating 1 with 3 and 2 with 4, i'm getting two possible values for $b =-3,3$, which one is valid?

In both cases i get the same set of 3 distinct solutions $x = a, a+6, a-6$

Comment: To check your solutions you can substitute $b=3$ and $b=-3$ in your equation and solve it again, to see if you get the three solutions you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, let's test them out.

$$||x-a|-3|=3$$

The left-hand side *before* the final modulus is applied must be either $\pm 3$ i.e. $|x-a|-3=3$ or $|x-a|-3=-3$. In the former case, $|x-a|=6$ will have the solutions $x=a+6$ and $x=-6+a$ (can you see why?). In the latter case, we get $|x-a|=0$ so $x=a$ is the unique solution.

That's three solutions.

Now let's try: $$||x-a|+3|=3$$

Either $|x-a|+3=3$ or $|x-a|+3=-3$. In the former case, $|x-a|=0$ so $x=a$. In the latter case, $|x-a|=-6$. This has no solutions (why?). So there is only one solution.

Thus, it is $b=3$ that we want.

---

This may also give you some insight into how you could have found the solutions without extra candidate solutions. How could we reason by cases about $||x-a|-3|=3$?

Comment: I get it now, modulus can never be a negative quantity like -6

Answer (score 0):

welcome to MSE:
$$f(x)=||x-a|-b|$$when $b>0$ is like $W$
so,when you need 3 distinct solution, you must check $$f(a)=|0-b|=b$$ and $b=+3$